# Floating Div in chrome clears the parent div

Tags: html, css

There is a parent div with variable height. In this parent div there are 2 more divs floating on left and right respectively. The background of parent div must end after both children divs. But it is not happening so in Chrome(IE working perfectly). The parent div background ends before the childrean div starts. If float is removed from children divs it it fine but then they are not next to each other.

Comment: This works better with an example. Or even better a demo on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Try to put `<div style="clear:left"></div>` see if this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `overflow: auto` on the parent div.

The problem is that floats aren't contained by their parents, unless their parents establish a new block formatting context. overflow: auto does just that, as do some other things (including floating - that is float the parent box and you contain the children floats).

**However**, establishing a new block formatting context is not necessary to achieve what you want, most people don't even do it that way.

Here's what you have right?

HTML

```
<div class="out">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

If below the floats you insert a new element (let's give it a class of cleardiv) and apply `clear: both` on it, it, the same element, will be pushed down below all the floated elements above it. And since it's not a floated element itself, it will be, as you'd expect, contained by the the parent element.
So, if it's contained by the parent element, and it's pushed to it's bottom, the parent element will have to be 'stretched' all the way to the bottom - just as you wanted.

Here's the new HTML

```
<div class="out">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="cleardiv"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

.cleardiv {
    clear: both;
}
```